# Strlen for strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have converted c++ to c type string and working with strlen but it is not working.

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string s("Hello");
s.c_str();
cout<<strlen(s);
}
```

Comment: Calling `s.c_str()` doesn't convert the `std::string` to a "c type string." It returns a pointer to the string held in the `std::string` which you ignore. So the statement, essentially, is a no-op. Try: `std::cout << strlen(s.c_str ())` or, better still, `std::cout << s.size()`

Comment: This line `s.c_str();` does nothing.

Comment: It is.....not working?  That's a pretty vague bug report. What's it supposed to do? What's it actually doing?

Comment: Congratulations! You just included the entire standard library AND pulled it all into the global namespace. I can't see this working well with anything non trivial. To explain: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` this includes the whole damn standard library or near enough to make no difference. That's a lot of extra compiling. `using namespace std;` makes everything in the std namespace global. You are setting yourself up for massive mystery bug nightmares with two lines of code. Don't do this to yourself.

Comment: @user4581301 We've got a [meme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) for this recently :-D ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I'm just thrilled to see both [Wave Motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kj4PSlqt4BQ)-calibre FUBAR cannons in use at the same time. The debugging will be epic.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> s.c_str();
> ```

This code has no side effects on `s` actually regarding a conversion or such. You want to process the result further.

Instead of

> ```
> cout<<strlen(s);
> ```

you want to have either

```
cout<<strlen(s.c_str());
```

or

```
cout<<s.size();
```

Where the latter is the certainly more efficient, because the standard requires a time complexity of O(1) for [`std::string::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), where `strlen()` cannot guarantee a better time complexity than `O(strlen(s))`.

Comment: I would make it clear that calling `string::size()` is an O(1) operation versus the O(n) operation of `strlen`.

Comment: @Mgetz Fair point! Upvoted their answer as well. Anyway the question looks doomed for me from long-term view.

Comment: no probably about the more efficient part at least C++11 requires `string::size()` to be O(1)

Comment: @Mgetz Changed from probability to certainly.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to waste clock-cycles in your processor:

```
 cout << strlen(s.c_str());
```

will count every character up to the first nul character in `s`.

If you just want to know how long the string is:

```
 cout << s.length();
```

or

```
 cout << s.size();
```

will give you that (and with an algorithm that is `O(1)` rather than the `strlen` algorithm that is `O(n)` - meaning that a million character long string takes one million times longer to measure the length of than a single character string). [Of course, if you have a `std::string` that contains a nul character in the middle, you may find that one of these methods is "right" and the other is "wrong" because it either gives too long or too short a length - a C style string is not allowed to contain a nul character in the middle of the string, it is only allowed as a termination]

Answer (score 0):

Why use `strlen` when the `string` class does the business?

Please read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string and not the size/length method

Otherwise do as the @πάντα ῥεῖ suggests